# Doctrine custom repository error

Tags: symfony, doctrine, repository-pattern

I've a brand new Symfony2 application and I'm 100% sure I've followed http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes to the letter. However I'm getting the following error;

```
Entity 'Core\MainBundle\Entity\LandingPromotions' has no field 'promotionType'. You can therefore not call 'findByPromotionType' on the entities' repository
```

I've no clue as to what I've missed. Code as follows;

**LandingPromotions**

```
<?php
namespace Core\MainBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* Core\MainBundle\Entity\LandingPromotions
*
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Core\MainBundle\Entity\PromotionRepository")
* @ORM\Table(name="landing_promotions")
*/
class LandingPromotions
{
//Normal entity stuff
}
```

**PromotionRepository.php**

```
namespace Core\MainBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class PromotionRepository extends EntityRepository
{
public function findByPromotionType($typeId)
{
}
}
```

**Controller**

```
namespace Core\MainBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Core\MainBundle\Entity\Game;
use Core\MainBundle\Entity\LandingPromotions as LandingPromotions;

class GameController extends Controller
{
/**
* @Route("{_locale}/games/")
* @Template()
*/
public function indexAction($_locale)
{
$lp_repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CoreMainBundle:LandingPromotions');

$lp_repo->findByPromotionType(2);
}
}
```

Comment: What's inside your entity ? (Where you wrote "//Normal entity stuff") The issue might comes from here

Comment: Standard getters and setters, e.g.`
    /**
    * @var integer $id
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
    */
    private $id;`

Comment: Do you have a promotionType variable ?

If you want to do a real custom query, don't start with "findBy", it's reserved to direct query on a column

Comment: Gist of the full entity https://gist.github.com/4443664. There isn't a promotionType, as I'm wanting a public method to query the database

Comment: Did you clear your cache? Seems like Doctrine is still using the generic repository.

Comment: try to var_dump the get_class of your repository, make sure it's your class being loaded, I think what's happening is it's failing to find your repository and using an autogenerated one and thus failing because there's no property named promotionType - did you try clearing the cache manually?

Comment: Dont start your custom function with findBy, try something like getByPromotionType to make your custom query as you don't have column named promotionType.

Comment: Doctrine is definitely using the default repository, doing a var_dump of get_class($lp_repo) returns `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository`. I've cleared all the doctrine caches and done a full clear cache (even gone as far a rm -r app/cache/).

Comment: Ok, next, try to rename your repository with the name of your class : "LandingPromotionsRepository" (in the file, in the repository, and in your entity)

Comment: Done that. Cleared all the caches and still the same error with the default repository loading.

Answer (score 1):

After much hair pulling and cursing I discovered that the entities are not using PHP annotations, but rather the XML versions. How this got mixed up I've no idea, but that'll be tomorrow's issue.